# How can I properly convert xhtml to csv?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I'm having trouble transforming a xhtml file to a csv using xslt.
The xhtml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Flight details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flight details</h1>
    <ul>
        <li id="nam">BLA145</li>
        <li id="reg">YK-LOL</li>
        <li id="hex">000100</li>
        <li id="alt">34950</li>
        <li id="spd">457</li>
        <li id="hdg">117</li>
        <li id="sqk">4774</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The stylesheet is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml xsl">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/ul/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@id='nam']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@id='reg']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@id='hex']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@id='alt']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@id='spd']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@id='hdg']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@id='sqk']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will result in no output. I've observed that if I remove

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

from the `<html >` tag, then the csv will be generated correctly.

Is this a namespace problem? How could I solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing namespace prefix for html elements(`xhtml:`). Since your output has all children of `ul`, you can use even this stylesheet rather than writing a template for every child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml xsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:html/xhtml:body/xhtml:ul/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly.Funny thing is that I've tried using the xhtml: namespace prefix in my style-sheet from above but I didn't worked; just printed the whole content by-passing the templates or nothing at all.